# TimeStamp and Datetime?

Tags: c#, mysql, console

I have use a timestamp on an 'updated' field, every time a new field is created or updated I want it to get the current timestamp. After I create a field I get 00-00 00:00:00 even though I only pass '' on creation. How do I fix it?

```
updated timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `null` in the insert statement

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc916/2)

Comment: `"INSERT INTO addresses (id, ads, updated) VALUES('" + _Start + "', '', '')";` This is what I used as a test and it doesn't seem to work, even though on update does work. Also default = current timestamp

Comment: use `INSERT INTO addresses (id, ads, updated) VALUES('" + _Start + "', '', NULL)`

Comment: And BTW you defined the timestamp  `ON UPDATE`. If you want it to be set at creation **and** on update, you have to use `default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp`